# Regular Expression with multiple matches - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have searched the web to find a similar problem but couldn't.

Here is an address:

> the fashion potential hq 116 w 23rd st ste 5 5th floor new york ny
>   10011

Using the following regex in python I tried to find the all possible main addresses in the above line:

```
re.findall(r'^(.*)(\b\d+\b)(.+)(\bst\b|\bste\b)(.*)$', 'the fashion potential hq 116 w 23rd st ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011')
```

I get result as:

`[('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd st ', 'ste', ' 5 5th floor new york ny 10011')]`.

I also want the result to include this: `('the fash....', '116', 'w 23rd ', 'st', 'ste 5 5th....')`. I expected `findall` would do the trick but didn't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

To make it clear what I want as output (or similar which includes all possibilities):
`[
('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd ', 'st', 'ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011'), 
('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd st ', 'ste', ' 5 5th floor new york ny 10011')]`

[Online Python code](http://pastebin.com/tJuJgDx1)

Comment: What do you mean you want it to include that stuff..isn't it already there?

Comment: Like [`^(.*)(\b\d+\b)(.+?)(\bste?\b)(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nT1iR4/1)?

Comment: @PeterWang: as `findall` returns all possible combinations, I expected my second result as well. But it does not have `st` in group(3). It only gives result with `ste` in group 3

Comment: It won't find overlapping matches. Each match starts from where the previous match ended.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I need it to be more generic, as I want to replace st, ste with ave, st, blvd etc

Comment: [`^(.*)(\b\d+\b)(.+?)(\b(?:ste|st|ave|blvd)\b)\s*(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nT1iR4/4)?

Comment: @Barmar: So, What are my options?

Comment: Use the regular expression to match the whole address, then find the strings within it that you want to replace with a separate `re.replace()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure y'all are missing OP's point. His regex works fine. He just wants to get all possible overlapping matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run 2 regex expressions, one with lazy dot and another with a greedy dot.

First one is [this](https://regex101.com/r/nT1iR4/7):

```
^(.*?)(\b\d+\b)(.+)\b(ste|st|ave|blvd)\b\s*(.*)$
```

The second one with the use lazy dot matching pattern inside:

```
^(.*?)(\b\d+\b)(.+?)\b(ste|st|ave|blvd)\b\s*(.*)$
                ^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT1iR4/8)

Output:

```
the fashion potential hq 
116
 w 23rd 
st
ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011
```

[Python sample code](http://ideone.com/xzO3fO):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(.*?)(\b\d+\b)(.+?)\b(ste|st|ave|blvd)\b\s*(.*)$')
p2 = re.compile(r'^(.*?)(\b\d+\b)(.+)\b(ste|st|ave|blvd)\b\s*(.*)$')
s = "the fashion potential hq 116 w 23rd st ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011"
m = p.search(s)
if m:
    n = p2.search(s)
    if n:
        print([m.groups(), n.groups()])
```

Results:

```
[
   ('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd ', 'st', 'ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011'), 
   ('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd st ', 'ste', '5 5th floor new york ny 10011')
 ]
```

Comment: If it is working as expected, I will add the pattern explanation.

Comment: Did you see his comment about wanting to use this to find all the abbreviations like `st` and `ste`, so he can replace them? Your code doesn't extract `ste` as a separate match.

Comment: @Barmar You are thinking that up. OP wants to replace the current `ste` and `st` matching parts in the regex pattern, not in the found results. Quote from the pastebin: *# also want to include this results: `('the fashion potential hq ', '116', ' w 23rd ', 'st', 'ste 5 5th floor new york ny 10011')`*  - just what my regex extracts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I am expecting to have all those possibilities (as Barmar explained) B'se I don't know which is going to be main address yet. So, I need all possibilities from that string to test it later.

Comment: @inblueswithu: It is up to you to put all possible alternations you need into the pattern. Use the alternation like `(ste|st|ave|blvd)` and add up more items when you find a new one.

Comment: @all: I have updated the question to what I'm expecting as a result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew He does have both possibilities. The problem is that the string contains multiple matches, it has both `st` and `ste`, and the regexp only finds the first one.

Comment: @Barmar: Well, surely it is not possible with 1 regex. However, using 2 variations solve the current issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is a good idea! But I guess it fails if `st` and `ste` are not next to each other. Say: `the fashion potential hq 116 w 23rd st 5 ste 5th floor new york ny 10011`. Both those two regex give same result.

Comment: @inblueswithu: Use lazy matching with the first `(.*)` -> `(.*?)`

Comment: Alright. Atleast it solved part of the problem. Thank you all!
Just to let you know, say if I add `ny` to my `st`, `ste` list it will still miss the `ste` result, even when used both regex expressions. 
I understand this is a complicated problem and may be I have to use multiple regex expressions to filter all those street tail names I have got (st, ave, blvd etc). However, I'm selecting this as correct answer as it gives me at least part of the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: It is possible that your question sounds a bit unclear. It is possible that you just want to match some specific repeated part inside a string. Then, it would not be hard to match it once the context is more or less defined. Here, with no concrete sepcifications, with just some arbitrary text, this really is a bit hard. Note that regex is just a pattern based engine, it has no semantics support, it cannot match from the same position twice or from an earlier position, either. It is sort of limited.